# C# WPF - один шаблон, множество элементов

Tags: c#, wpf

Мне необходимо создать 40 текстовых полей с лейблами, можно ли как-то  обойтись без копи-паста, а просто создать шаблон? Я прочитал об этом в интернете, но не понял до конца. Каждая связка (TextBox и Label) заворачивается в StackPanel:

```
<StackPanel MinWidth="180" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5">
    <Label Content="{DynamicResource "Название метки"}" Margin="0" Padding="0"></Label>
    <TextBox Padding="5" Text="{Binding "Здесь название свойства"}"  Height="27" ></TextBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 2):

Для этого есть два варианта:

1. Создать UserControl и разместить разметку в нём, а потом 40 раз использовать его.
2. Создать DataTemplate с необходимой разметкой и потом приметить его к 40 ContentControl'ам.

Comment: Интересно, с чем удобнее работать в коде, если генерировать эти 40 интерактивно через код по запросу из UI? Или какой вариант вы бы сами выбрали и почему?

Comment: @Bulson, Оба варианта прекрасно применяются через код. Я бы выбрал UserControl, так как он требует меньше кода(просто создать), а для ContentControl нужно ещё найти ресурс с DataTemplate и применить.

Comment: @ Kibnet Philosoff спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Если вам нужно создать множество элементов, кроме уже упомянутых `UserControl`'а и `DataTemplate` вам может пригодится `ItemsControl` (особенно если вы пишете с использованием MVVM).

Ваш код при этом будет примерно таким:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding TextDescriptionCollection}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:SingleTextDescriptionVM}">
            <StackPanel MinWidth="180" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5">
                <Label Content="{Binding FieldName}" Margin="0" Padding="0"/>
                <TextBox Padding="5" Text="{Binding FieldValue}" Height="27" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Вы можете поменять контейнер элементов, если вам нужен невертикальный лэйаут.